# Interactive rebase vim customization not working

Tags: vim, rebase

Using settings such as

```
set cc=80
```

does not work when using vim for an interactive rebase.

Comment: You can use `:verbose set cc?` to check where the setting got overridden.

Comment: @IngoKarkat Vim warns with "ES19: Option not supported: cc"

Comment: Well, there you have the answer. Git is probably using an older version of Vim; you can check with `:version` and `:echo v:progpath`. You probably need to update the `core.editor` git config setting, or the `EDITOR` environment variable (onto which Git falls back) to point to the desired Vim executable.

Comment: That's a good guess, but I don't see how my vim version could be out of date given that it is the same version that I use in my terminal that does support cc (8.0).

Comment: Maybe it's launching it as `vi` rather than `vim` so it's shutting off "advanced" features? `set compatible?` may give some clues. Check (and set?) your `EDITOR` environment variable to be `vim`.

Comment: I chose my editor in git config, I set my env var to vim to try that. Didn't change things. It would seem that the editor starts in `set compatible` sadly `set nocompatible` doesn't change the editor